# html tag details doesn't work for android html viewer

Tags: android, html

In sample code html where use the tag details when the html code is read via html viewer in android enviroment doesn't work properly.
The first tag details works fine, but the second tag and son on...doesn't work properly.
The collaps/expande remain always in the content "+".

below the html code

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, width=device-width" />
<style>
summary {cursor: pointer; font: bold 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 8px 0; position: relative; width: 100%; }
summary::-webkit-details-marker {display: none}
summary:after{background: darkblue;  border-radius: 5px; content: "+"; color: #fff; float: left; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin: -5px 10px 0 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 30px;}
details[open] summary:after {content: "-";}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header> 
 <details>
        <summary>
          Sample 1
        </summary>
 <p>In few simple steps (see below), you can download and perform the registration. sdjsadjaksjdaskjdasddasdasd Incoming and Outgoing Calls are shown and the Error messages are explained.sadiaus  sadasdjasdjasl sdadjaskdjaslkdjsajdlaskjdlasjdsajd sdfahjahdj</p> 
</details>
<details>
        <summary>
          Sample 2
        </summary>
        <p>In few simple steps (see below), you can download and perform the registration. sdjsadjaksjdaskjdasddasdasd Incoming and Outgoing Calls are shown and the Error messages are explained.sadiaus  sadasdjasdjasl sdadjaskdjaslkdjsajdlaskjdlasjdsajd sdfahjahdj</p>
</details>  
</header>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"`  this `>` tag is misssing

Comment: Thanks, I add the missing tag, but the result on android side html viewer is always the same. The second collaps/expande is always "+".

Comment: try adding style inside `<details>`

Comment: Thanks, If I add the style inside the details I miss the the new content "+" and "-" ( I see the default content ">" of the tag details).

Comment: try this meta viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">